# Best method of including base/global styles in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

When adding base/global styles in Vue, is it best practice to require them in my `main.js`?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store/';

require('./assets/scss/main.scss');

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Or is it better to import them in my `App.vue`?

```
<style lang="scss">

    @import 'src/assets/scss/main.scss';

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference importing in App.vue or in main.js, just do not forget that the style tag in App.vue must not have the attribute scoped or the import will not work, I personally prefer to do inside the main.js, but with vue-cli 3 IMHO this approach is much better:

**vue.config.js**

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // pass options to sass-loader
      sass: {
        // @/ is an alias to src/
        // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.scss`
        data: `@import "@/variables.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: Do not forget that in vue, when importing modules, you can use the alias @ that maps into the /src folder of files.

In a project of mine I have this import in main.js
`import '@/assets/scss/index.scss';`

For more information: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html